# Chrome devtools, CPU throttle - gaps in instrumentation or something else?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, profiling

I am trying to profile some code - for an event click leading to a rendering of a HTML table, with CPU throttling (6x slowdown) using Chrome devtools. I see gaps in the performance profile of the event handled on the main thread.

Anyone know what these are?  Screenshot attached.

My environment config - Chrome 63.0.3239.132 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.2

[image: Chrome devtools, CPU 6x slowdown, gaps in function calls on a click event handled on the main thread]

Comment: That's how throttling works.

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm.  trying to understand this further.  when you say this is how throttling works,  what exactly is happening behind the scenes?  is a specific function invocation and the instructions there in being put on hold?

Comment: I mean it technically works that way. The browser waits a certain time between running code. On the other hand, it would make sense if devtools timeline offered an option to automatically join the samples into contiguous blocks so you may open a ticket on https://crbug.com if there is none already.

Comment: Cool. thanks a lot for the explanation @wOxxOm